# How can I use drawCallback to execute code after data has been retrieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Using DataTables plugin what I am attempting to do is:

1. Get data from function `GetData1`
2. Once data is retrieved store that data in `var dataQuery1`
3. Get data from function `GetData2`
4. Add `dataQuery1` rows to table

It's takes a while to get data from function `GetData1`. Hence no data is getting stored in `dataQuery1` [dataQuery1.length shows up as zero]. I thought `drawCallback`was supposed to take care of this. Instead I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.

```
var resourcetable = $('#table').DataTable({
"ajax": {
"url": "QueryDataService.asmx/GetData1",
"dataSrc": ""
},
"columns": [
    { "data": "Column1" },
    { "data": "Column2" },
    { "data": "Column3" }
],
"drawCallback": function (settings) {
     var dataQuery1 = resourcetable.data(); //Point of Failure
     alert('The table has ' + dataQuery1.length + ' rows');//Shows zero rows
     resourcetable.ajax.url("QueryDataService.asmx/GetData2").reload();
     resourcetable.rows.add(data).draw()
});
```

Is there anyways to execute steps 2, 3, 4 AFTER step 1 is complete?

Comment: What is resourceusagetable? Is it another datatables instance, or is that a typo and supposed to be resourcetable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One Datatables.net table with multiple ajax calls from Sharepoint 2010 REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344909/one-datatables-net-table-with-multiple-ajax-calls-from-sharepoint-2010-rest-api)

Comment: Adam, that I was a typo on my part. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link Gyrocode.com. I used $.when(x,y).done(function(a,b){} to get the two json data sets and then used $.merge to combine the data.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my final solution for the benefit of others.

```
var set1 = $.ajax({
            url: "Url1.asmx/GetData1",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });

var set2 = $.ajax({
            url: "Url2.asmx/GetData2",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });

$.when(set1, set2).done(function (dataset1, dataset2) {
            var data = $.merge(dataset1[0], dataset2[0]);
            $('#table').DataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "data": "Column1" },
                    { "data": "Column2" },
                    { "data": "Column3" }
                ]
            });
        });
```