# DataTables.net - multiple ajax sources

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I couldn't find any information on the (very huge) documentation of datatables concerning the question of multiple ajax sources.

So I have a first source:

```
"ajax": {
   "url": "components/table_accountingin.php?type=incomes",
   "dataSrc": 'patients'
},
```

And I'd like to have a second url getting the data from another source. Is that possible ? The function generating the json data is quite complex so I'd like to avoid putting all calls in the same php function !
I tried to put sources between brackets etc. but that obviously didn't work out as expected !

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking how to join two data sources on the same table?

Comment: Yes, two ajax sources !

Comment: Does it matter if the sources have different number of rows or columns, and do you want them joined side by side or union stacked on top of each other?

Comment: No it should be easy, same columns and number of them !

Comment: I can even give them the same names for the column attribute !

Comment: So, stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Exactly, the rendering should take care of the order by date I think :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One Datatables.net table with multiple ajax calls from Sharepoint 2010 REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344909/one-datatables-net-table-with-multiple-ajax-calls-from-sharepoint-2010-rest-api)

Comment: Can't you just call the second function from the first php function?
Otherwise, you should make the two ajax calls, and when the two calls are finished, join the data into a single array and initialize datatables with it as its source.